# Compiz antialiasing with xserver-xorg-video-radeon?

Tags: compiz, metacity, amd-graphics, antialiasing

Window previews are ugly on my computer:

[image: compiz]

Is there any solution to make them smooth? BTW window previews in Metacity with composition enabled (`/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager`) are looking much better than in Compiz.

[image: metacity]

I am using the open source radeon driver, so I can't configure my videocard preferences via AMD's GUI, and I've tried all options like a texture filter, bicubic filter or mipmapping I found in ccsm with no result.

How to make window previews in Compiz be as smooth as they are in Metacity?

And sorry, my English sucks just like these window thumbnails in Compiz.

Comment: you might wanna attach screenshots the rest of us can all go get disgusted of how ugly it was before it got pretty

Comment: Yeah, I tried to, but I don't have enough reputation points :( http://ubuntuone.com/p/X5u/ — compiz, http://ubuntuone.com/p/X5v/ — metacity

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't think of that. May I advice you ask another question (that haven't been asked here before) and/or browse around to see if you can answer anything to gain the 10 rep you need to post images.

Comment: I've added the links (which are leading to the screenshots) into my comment above. Just look closer ;)

Comment: @ eXtractor: try to disable transparency in Compiz?

Comment: @Tshepang: upvoting questions gives rep scores too ;)

Comment: @Tak I like to upvote a question when I can reasonably understand it.

Comment: @Takkat i haven't try, but I think it's not gonna help.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is an internal compiz issue - not necessarily one of aliasing. The window buffer is sent to this little window preview and scaled down, giving it that crunchy feel. Perhaps you should report a bug dealing with that plugin.

Comment: let's see how they will respond https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/709721